# CDI: How to put an existing object into application scope (without writing CDI extension)?

Tags: cdi

I have an object which I initialized manually (legacy code).
I'd like to put this object to the application context to make it available through CDI.

How do I do that without writing a CDI extension?

Answer (score 4):

Using a producer. Make a bean that `@Produces` instances of your class.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have `@Produces` method in the same bean which `@Inject`s it? Can I delay the initialization somehow to achieve this without creating circular dependency? There's `Instance<...>` but I'd have to create one more field to keep the actual bean...

Comment: how will a circular dependency appear? The producer does not depend on its consumer usually

Comment: Then how do I CDI-ize  `this.foo = new Foo(this)`?

Comment: so you do need a circular reference (with or without CDI).. well, CDI supports circular references through proxies, so just inject in the producer, and inject the produced object in the original one.

Comment: is "this" a CDI bean? Is "this" Application scoped? In which case as "Foo" is also application scoped it may be better just to leave Foo as dependent scope and effectively outside the management of CDI. Depends on how you want to access Foo. I guess there's only one of "this" and only one of "Foo" but they relate? Can you produce a third class with only @Producers that instantiates both "This" and "Foo"? Does it make sense to inject "Foo" into "This" if Foo's constructor is so connected? Or do you need a Foo Factory if the intent is to be able to use alternative Foos?

Comment: if you really have the need for instantiating new objects under the control of the cdi container you can either use producer methods as correctly stated above or an alternative for you might be: 

    `@Inject private Instance<Foo> myFooInstanceProvider;
    public void someMethod(){
    Foo myFoo = myFooInstanceProvider.get();
    // do stuff with myFoo
    }`

The instance myFoo will be provided by the CDI container.

To sum it up: if you want to make an object instance CDI aware without writing an extension then `Instance<>` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like that?

```
@ApplicationScoped  
public class ApplicationScopedClass {   

    @Produces  
    public static ApplicationScopedClass makeAnInstance() {  
      return new ApplicationScopedClass();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to pointing out, I'm new here do not know yet all the things

Comment: You are welcome and don't worry, it's absolutely normal. When you have some time, here's a link for a [Mini-Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out how this little community works. Cheers.